# SSH failing to connect

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to set up an SSH connection to my DDWRT router.   I followed instructions on generating a key pair in the Ubuntu documentation SSH/OpenSSH/Keys but I'm not able to connect.

The debug output from `ssh -vT <my router>` is below.

I'd be very grateful to know what the problem might be. (I have transferred the public key into DDWRT by pasting it in.   I can connect using Putty from Windows and also using the vSSH app from my iPod, but now, in trying to get to grips with Ubuntu, I'm hoping to similarly connect.)

```
martin@martin-Reserved:~$ ssh -vT 192.168.1.1
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_0.52
debug1: no match: dropbear_0.52debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 49:bb:ab:82: (blocked out by me):46:2f:72
debug1: Host '192.168.1.1' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/martin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
DD-WRT v24-sp2 mini (c) 2009 NewMedia-NET GmbH
Release: 07/22/09 (SVN revision: 12548)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/martin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/martin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/martin/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 5):

By default, if a username is not specified, `ssh` (and related tools) will try to user your current username. The DD-WRT router, however, has only the `root` user, and this is where the SSH key is stored.

You need to instead run `ssh root@192.168.1.1` to log in into your router.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That was the problem.  I spent a few hours searching Google results associated with the permission denied (publickey) message, and the answer was so simple.   Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: You're welcome. Please click on the checkmark (below the up/down buttons) to mark this as the answer.